# php counter variable across multiple form files

Tags: php

I have multiple pages.  On each page I have a list of items.  So on Page 1, I have Items 1-10.  On page 2, I have items 11-20.  It is NOT ten items per page but the point is that page 3 should start off with the number immediately following the last number on page 2.

The pages have a simple numeric variable so the counting of items works fine per page but I want it to be set in one place.

I am brand new to php so my question is mostly about how and where to store a variable that would keep track of this item count over multiple files?

Desired behavior:

Let's say Page 1 has 5 items and my counter variable on page 1 sets them to be correctly numbered to:

```
1.apple
2.grape
3.pear
4.banana
5.orange
```

But let's say I need to remove banana.  When I do so, the current counter on page 1 works fine and sets to:

```
1.apple
2.grape
3.pear
4.orange
```

But on page 2 the counter variable is set to 6 and has:

```
6.mango
7.peach
8.watermelon
```

I want to set the persistent variable so that when I remove a fruit, it will update not only the current page the removed fruit is on but every page after that. So it would adjust page 2 to:

```
5.mango
6.peach
7.watermelon
```

Would sessions make that change permanent or would it disappear with the user's cookie?

Comment: Has long has the cookie dont die the session should work just fine. remember you can store anything in $_SESSION['yourSESSION'] but if you want it to be the same always You could also store your counter in a DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//On the first line of your PHP code
session_start();

//then store your variable in the SESSION array.
$_SESSION['yourCountersNameHere'] = 56;

//You should now have acces to its value from page to page like this

echo $_SESSION['yourCountersNameHere'];
//Should display 56.
?>
```

you could also store it in a DB. and then check in the DB on every page.

```
//to connecte
$m_DB = new PDO("mysql:host=".$Host.";dbname=".$DBName."; charset=utf8", $Login, $Password);

//check value in DB
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = $m_DB->prepare($query);
//$param here is empty but normaly it would be a array for all your params like this:
//$param = array('rowname'=>$value, 'rowName2'=>$value2, .........and so on for all the $params you use.);

$getCounter = $stmt->execute($param);
while($Counter = $getCounter->fetch())
{
    //Display the value in your MySQLDB.
    echo $Counter['table.rowName'];
}
```

If you use another DB type than MYSQL the code should be fairly the same exepte for a couple of changes you'll have to make.

Comment: I think I may not have phrased my question well.  I don't want the item numbering to be based on a user's temporary session.  Please see question edit above.  But my understanding is very new.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php for more information using sessions.

Any variable that is placed in a session will be persistent for the user as long as their cookie doesn't expire.

Answer (score -1):

On each page of your site that will access/change your page variable, add this code at the very beginning:

```
<?php
//On the very first line of each file using the variable
session_start();
```

Then for accessing/setting see the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This code will spit out one from the session variable 'views'

To check if something has been set:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    //do something
```

Clearing out the session variables:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
  unset($_SESSION['views']);
?>
```

Deleting the session:

```
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

Best site in the universe : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Not the best site of the universe but still the information is correct

Comment: w3schools is known for having misleading or incorrect information, so that's probably where the -1 came from, despite your answer being more detailed than another answer using the same idea.

Comment: it should be a plus one for giving the OP a priceless and free resource for web development.